# How do you split this right down the middle...knife tool isn't helping

Tags: modeling

[image]

How do I cut this cleanly in half...got the knife tool to wrap around it but anytime I select it wants to grab all the lines coming into it from both sides and all I want to do it cut this into 2 pieces and into 2 separate objects but cutting a straight line seems to be hard to do.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are wanting to achieve. Is the attached image the result you want, or is that the starting point?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Want to make a clean-through cut where the dotted black line is and separate the object into 2 pieces.

Answer (score 1):

when you are in edit mode...

1. press k (knife tool) -> in the bottom bar text appears
2. select any start point you want by clicking with left mouse button
3. press A (angle constraint) -> in the bottom bar now there should appear (screen) instead of "off"
4. press C (in the bottom bar now appears cut through (ON instead of OFF)
5. now you will see when moving your mouse that you can easily make vertical cuts
6. left click your second point to cut through the whole object by pressing return afterwards

[image]

Comment: Already used the cut-through function, it is how I got the line through the middle. But if I select that line it grabs the lines coming in horizontally from it as well when I try to separate the object into 2.